# Locale-aware string formatting using .format() syntax

Tags: python, locale, string-formatting

Is there a (general) way to do locale-aware string formatting in Python using the `.format()` `{:}` syntax? I know of `locale.format_string()`, but this only accepts the old `%` syntax. `{:n}` exists, but only works as a replacement of `{:d}`, not for the other formats.

My current approach is below, which I expect will break for most non-trivial cases.

```
import locale
import string


class LocaleFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def format_field(self, value, format_spec):
        if format_spec[-1] not in 'eEfFgGdiouxXcrs':  # types copied from locale._percent_re
            return super().format_field(value, format_spec)
        grouping = ',' in format_spec or '_' in format_spec
        format_spec = '%' + format_spec.replace(',', '').replace('_', '')
        return locale.format_string(format_spec, value, grouping)


locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
fmt = LocaleFormatter()
fmt.format("Length: {:,.2f} mm, width: {:,.2f} mm", 1234.56, 7890)  # expected format is 1.234,56 for most locales
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want converting the float to `decimal` and setting the precision as well as manually adding leading spaces if needed:

```
import decimal
import locale
import re
import string

class LocaleFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def format_field(self, value, format_spec):
        if format_spec[-1] not in 'eEfFgGdiouxXcrs':  # types copied from locale._percent_re
            return super().format_field(value, format_spec)
        grouping = ',' in format_spec or '_' in format_spec
        prec_re = re.match(r',?(?P<spec>(?P<width>\d+)?(.(?P<precision>\d+))?)?[eEfFgGdiouxXcrs]', format_spec)
        if prec_re is not None and prec_re.group('spec') is not None:
            space_len = prec_re.group('width')
            after_dot = prec_re.group('precision')
            if after_dot is not None:
                pre_dot_value_len = len(str(int(value)))
                ctx = decimal.Context(prec=int(after_dot) + pre_dot_value_len)
                # prec turned out to be the length of the decimal repr, not precision
                value = ctx.create_decimal(value)
            if space_len is not None:
                after_dot = 0 if after_dot is None else int(after_dot)
                pre_dot = len(str(value))
                how_many = pre_dot - after_dot - 1  # -1 for the dot character
                if how_many > 0:
                    format_spec = how_many * ' ' + format_spec
        format_spec = '%' + format_spec.replace(',', '').replace('_', '')
        return locale.format_string(format_spec, value, grouping)

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'DE-DE')
fmt = LocaleFormatter()
res = fmt.format("Length: {:,.2f} mm, width: {:,2f} mm", 1234.567878, 7890)  # expected format is 1.234,56 for most locales
print(res)
```

Which results in:

```
Length: 1.234,57 mm, width:         7.890,000000 mm
```

Please note that the value you suggested as the correct one after formatting is not properly rounded. The one above - is.

Comment: My question was explicitly about using the existing string formatting syntax, so I don't think that having to use Babel's own formatting language is the right answer to that. Then  I could just as well use `locale.format_string()`. 

I also don't think that Babel accepts general strings, only numbers (i.e. the equivalent of `"Length: {:,.2f} mm, width: {:,.2f} mm".format(1234.56, 7890)`). I've made this a bit more clear in the question.

Comment: @BrtH: please see now - I revised it so that to better answer your question.